# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{6} \zeta_7^k= 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, geometric-progressions

I have tried this complex analysis problem for hours on my own but am still stumped.

> Suppose $\zeta_7 = e^{2\pi i/7} = \cos(2\pi/7)+i\sin(2\pi/7)$. Prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{6} \zeta_7^k = 0.$$

I have so far obtained that $$\sum_{k=0}^{6} (\zeta_7)^k = 1 + (\zeta_7) + (\zeta_7)^2 + (\zeta_7)^3 +(\zeta_7)^4 +(\zeta_7)^5 + (\zeta_7)^6,$$ but that's as far as I get.

Comment: Do you know how to sum a finite geometric series $1+r+r^{2}+\ldots+r^{n}$?

Comment: [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would make your question look nicer.  Did you want to put $k$ in the title?

Comment: I do, but I've tried it for this specific problem and am still confused.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$\zeta ^7 = \cos 2\pi +i \sin 2\pi =1$$

Therefore, $$ \zeta ^7-1=0$$

That is $$ (\zeta -1 )(\zeta ^6 + \zeta ^5 +...+\zeta +1) =0$$

Since $\zeta \ne 1$ we have $\zeta -1 \ne 0$.

Thus $$\zeta ^6 + \zeta ^5 +...+\zeta +1 =0$$

Answer (score 4):

Because $$\sum_{k=0}^6\zeta^k=\frac{\zeta^7-1}{\zeta-1}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $X^7-1=0$ has no repeated roots (can be checked by looking at the derivative of $X^7-1$)
and $\zeta_7$ is one of the roots,

The 7 numbers, $\zeta_7^k,k=0,1,\ldots, 6$ are also solutions of the same equation.

The have to be all the solutions, as we are dealing with the a 7th degree equation.

Your question requires finding the sum of all the roots of the equation.

For any equation of degree $n$ sum of all its (real/complex) roots  (counting multiplicity)
is the negative of the coefficient of $X^{n-1}$,  In the case we are discussing $X^6$ term is not present hence the sum is zero.